# How to put a message in VS Code Problems window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension which enforces a json schema onto a json file. When there is an error, it posts a message into the Problems window which is great.

How can I write to this window, from my extension, to put my own messages in the Problems window?

I have searched the docs, and could only find showInformationMessage, showErrorMessage and showWarningMessage but none of these put the message anywhere visible that I can see.

Any hints to the correct method or a suitable doc page would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *diagnostics* for this. The starting point for that API is `createDiagnosticCollection()` from the [`vscode.languages` namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_languages). vscode-extension-samples has a [simple example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/diagnostic-related-information-sample/src/extension.ts) for this. The basic idea is that [`DiagnosticCollection`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DiagnosticCollection) acts as a map with URIs as keys and arrays of diagnostics as values.